# can't get simple mysql function to work

Tags: mysql, function

I want to create a function in mysql that replaces html entities or other special characters in a string. But I can't get it to work. I am new in writing functions.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION cleanEntities(s varchar(255))
RETURNS varchar(255)
BEGIN
s = replace(s, '&amp;',char(0x0026 using utf8))
s = replace(s, '&uuml;', char(0xc3bc using utf8))
RETURN s$$
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I had to remove the ; in the error message, so the &amp etc. is not shown as HTML.

Error Message

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= replace(s, '&amp',char(0x0026 using utf8)) s = replace(s, '&uuml', char(0xc' at line 4

Comment: Define "can't get it to work." Errors? Not doing what it's supposed to? Volcanoes erupt near you?

Comment: added the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION cleanEntities(s varchar(255))
RETURNS varchar(255)
BEGIN
set s = replace(s, '&amp;',char(0x0026 using utf8));
set s = replace(s, '&uuml;', char(0xc3bc using utf8));
RETURN s;
END $$


DELIMITER ;
```